# Take user input and come up print if the combination of concatenations are prime numbers

Tags: python

I am trying to figure how to take a user input of numbers that are comma separated (eg: 1,7) and print out if their concatenated combinations are prime numbers (eg. 7, 17, 71).

**So far, the steps i take is:**

```
#convert user input into a list
values = input("Input some comma separated numbers : ")

num = values.split(",")
```

**But i do not know what to do after to come up with all their combination in a form of a list like:** 
num_combination = [1, 7 , 17, 71].

If i can convert them like the above, i think i can write a function like:

```
answer = []
for i in num_combination:
    if i > 1 and i%i ==0:
        answer.append(i)
    else:
        pass
```

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Check out https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations

Comment: Also, your condition `i > 1 and i%i == 0` is not going to work to detect prime numbers. It will actually be true for all numbers. The condition you need to put here is i > 1 and all numbers less than i do not divide i

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out! Very sorry as i am still new to programming

Answer (score 0):

So, I wasn't planning to answer this question, because I felt that the comments I had left would put you on the right track, but the question you have posted seems to have some interesting sub-problems, that would be interesting (and hopefully useful) to tackle.

#### 1. How do I convert a line of text into an array of numbers?

You currently have this code:

```
#convert user input into a list
values = input("Input some comma separated numbers : ")

num = values.split(",")
```

Now, this code is part of what needs to be done. There's actually one step missing in the code mentioned above, because right now, `num` is an array containing strings

```
>>> num
["1", "7"]
```

To convert it into an array of numbers, you will also need to run the `int` function on all elements in the array. There are multiple ways of doing this:

```
new_num = list(map(int, num))
# OR
new_num = []
for v in num: new_num.append(int(v))
# OR
new_num = [int(v) for v in num]
```

#### 2. How do I get all possible permutations and combinations of elements in an array?

Now, luckily for us, Python provides us with a utility that does at least part of our work for us. [`itertools.permutations`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations). This function takes two parameters: the array, and the number of elements to provide as permutations:

```
>>> itertools.permutations(['A','B','C'], 2)
[('A', 'B'), ('A', 'C'), ('B', 'A'), ('B', 'C'), ('C', 'A'), ('C', 'B')]
```

But for our case, we need all length permutations, so we'll have to do something a little more complex:

```
num_permutations = []
for i in range(1,len(num)):
    num_permutations += list(itertools.permutations(num, i))
```

There are other ways to get this list of permutations, without having a native function, but they're a little more detailed than necessary for this solution. I'll cover them if I have time later.

#### 3. How do I find Prime numbers?

The definition of a prime number is a number that has prime factors of just `1` and itself. That means, to check if `k` is a prime number, one needs to ensure that all the numbers in (`2`, `3`, ..., `k-2`, `k-1`) do not divide `k`.

The easiest way to do that is

```
def is_prime(k):
    prime = True
    for i in range(2,k):
        if k%i == 0:
            prime = False
            break

    return prime
```

There are a lot of optimisations that can be done on this, but again, I won't go into them right now.

#### 4. Putting it all together

There is one small edge-case that I have left out above. How do I convert a tuple of digits into an actual number? That's part of what the code below does:

```
def is_prime(k):
    prime = True
    for i in range(2, k):
        if k%i == 0:
            prime = False
            break

    return prime


values = input("Input some comma separated numbers : ")
num = map(int, values.split(","))

permutations = []
for i in range(1, len(num)):
    for t in itertools.permutations(num, i):
        str_num = int("".join(map(str, t)))
        permutations.append(str_num)

answer = []
for i in permutations:
    if is_prime(i):
        answer.append(i)

print(answer)
```